# Can we use fft algorithm for find Fourier Series coefficients?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

wen can easily find a0, a1 and b1 coefficients with classical formula. Also Matlab or that kind of program have built in fft functions and we can find fft of any non-periodic function. I just want to learn can we use fft for finding coefficients for any periodic function?